# Merge Angular CLI project with start.spring.io projects?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, github

a question about merging these two projects into one repo for github.

I have created an Angular project by using the Angular-CLI.
I have also created a Spring boot project using start.spring.io.

I placed these two projects into one folder 'my-project'.
One of the problems I'm having is that I cannot push 'my-project' onto github repo. However, I can push Angular / spring separately. How do I merge these two project into one repo?

Comment: Would be appreciated if u guys can help me out instead of being negative :( or maybe point me a link that shows me how to do it. I can't find the source.

Answer (score 0):

If `my-project` folder is supposed to be *one* repo, with the Angular/spring in it, then you can:

- either reference your Angular/spring repo as a submodule in `my-project`
- or copy the Angular/spring content (minus its .git folder) in my-project, add, commit and push.

In both instances, make sure you have `git init` in `my-project` folder, added your empty GitHub repo as a remote URL, add, commit, and (for the first push), `git push -u origin master`.